# sql server aggregate function(sum)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

Say I have a table like this

```
|  Person_ID   |    DATE    |   STATUS   |  HOURS  |
----------------------------------------------------
|     001      |   April 3  |     OK     |  3.000  |
|     001      |   April 4  |     BAD    |  3.000  |
|     001      |   April 3  |     BAD    |  4.000  |
|     002      |   April 3  |     OK     |  2.000  | 
|     002      |   April 5  |     BAD    |  3.000  |
```

and I want to achieve something like this..

```
|  Person_ID   |  TOTAL(OK)  | TOTAL(BAD) | OVERALL(OK+BAD)|
------------------------------------------------------------
|     001      |    3.000    |  7.000     |    10.000      |
|     002      |    2.000    |  3.000     |    5.000       |
```

I have done something like this before but only for individual `Person_ID`.
In this case, I've tried `grouping` and using `sum` but it's not actually the target result because I cant group the same `Person_ID` as one like the result above. 
I can actually achieve this but with multiple api request, but I don't think that's a good practice. I want it only on one request.
Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following with `CASE` statement within `SUM()` function.

```
select
    Person_Id,
    sum(case when status = 'OK' then hours end) as `TOTAL(OK)`,
    sum(case when status = 'BAD' then hours end) as `TOTAL(BAD)`.
    sum(case when status = 'OK' OR status = 'BAD' then hours end) as `TOTAL(OK + BAD)`
from yourTable
group by
   Person_Id
```